# Meeting Workspace Permissions in Outlook 2010

Tags: 2010, permissions, outlook, meeting-workspace

I have a series of meeting workspaces in SP2010 which have different permissions depending on the AD group of the user (ie. HR employees can see the HR Meeting Space, accounts can the Accounting Meeting Space etc. Everyone can see the Demo Meeting Space).

This works perfectly within Sharepoint itself, with staff able to access only the relevant meeting spaces and the menu displaying links accordingly.

However, in Outlook when they come to link to an existing meeting space, the majority of users can only see the Demo Meeting space and not the others for which they have permission.

Even if they have "Full Control" granted directly they cannot see them.

Is this a bug or a known stumbling block?

Comment: Surely Metting Workspace is a part of Sharepoint, but your question still feels off topic for this exchange

Comment: Surely that depends on if the problem lies with Sharepoint or Outlook, which at this time I do not know. As the issue is Sharepoint related, then surely this exchange is the place for it as I am asking the Sharepoint experts.

Comment: Agree, but you said it looked fine from Sharepoint? :)

Comment: Yes, but it is Sharepoint that sends the information to Outlook